# SVG rectangle with dashed background

Tags: svg

I have multiple rectangles filled with varying colors.
Some of them I need them to be filled with dashed-background and still retain the original fill color.

Something like:

```
<rect class="one" y="0" x="0" width="100" height="100" />
<rect class="one dashed" y="0" x="110" width="100" height="100" />
<rect class="two" y="110" x="0" width="100" height="100" />
```

I've tried to get it done with a pattern definition, but I just get a white background.
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AyKarsi/eLbvem92/

Disregarding my above attempt, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you can't apply two different fills to an element.  You will need to overlay two elements.

```
<rect class="one" y="0" x="110" width="100" height="100" />
<rect class="dashed" y="0" x="110" width="100" height="100" />
```

Also, your pattern definition is wrong, which is why it doesn't show up.  Below is a corrected version:

```
<pattern id="dashedBackground"  width="6" height="48" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image xlink:href="http://app.absence.io/assets/images/absence_pattern.png"
           x="0" y="0" width="6" height="50" />
</pattern>
```

I've had to clip your image a little because it doesn't repeat properly at a height of 50.  It does at 48 though.  I assume that's what you wanted.

[Here is a fully working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/eLbvem92/3/)

**Update**

Actually there is a way to do it, without multiple overlays, by using filters.

```
<svg width="400" height="410">
    <defs>
        <filter id="dashedBackground" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feImage xlink:href="http://app.absence.io/assets/images/absence_pattern.png" x="0" y="0" width="6" height="48" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"/>
            <feTile x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
                <feMergeNode/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>               
    </defs>

    <rect width="100" height="100" transform="translate(110,0)"
          fill="green" filter="url(#dashedBackground)"/>
</svg>
```

One disadvantage though is, because of how feTile works, you have to position the shape using a transform.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/eLbvem92/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to achieve the desired effect by overlaying a second rectangle:

```
<rect class="one" y="0" x="110" width="100" height="100" />
<rect class="dashed" y="0" x="150" width="100" height="100" />
```

See this fiddle for a full working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/AyKarsi/t8gzep39/